# Update query in TSQL throwing error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to run an update query, seems simple enough I am updating all the fields InitialCharge to a value of '21.61' everywhere that the current InitialCharge = '20.72', I also have some other qualifying fields. I am getting the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Here is my query, I tried using "IN" and "Exists" but neither work:

```
 update [dbo].[tTransactionHistory]
  set InitialCharge = '21.61'
   Where exists( 

                        select InitialCharge from [dbo].[tTransactionHistory]
                         where ProcedureID = '-747422922' and InitialCharge = ('20.72') and (DateOfService >= '09/01/2014' and DateOfService < '10/01/2014')

                         )
```

I even tried a simple update query and I get the error, Ive never run into this issue trying to just update several fields

```
  update [dbo].[tTransactionHistory]
  set InitialCharge = '21.61'
  where InitialCharge = '20.72'
```

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLDSn.png)

Comment: you need to correlate your query ,in case you are using exists

Comment: I tried just doing a straight up update as well not using Exists or in and it got that error

Comment: Can you explain out the logic here? What records require the update?

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: The issue is a VB6 app that I dont have the source code to is using an incorrect Rate that this company charges. Its hardcoded in the app. So rather than have them manually edit 300 records I am trying to update it in SQL which I thought would be simple :/

Comment: *The problem is in the trigger, which is named in the error message. **Always READ the error message you get.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by why you need an EXISTs subquery at all...

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tTransactionHistory]
SET InitialCharge = '21.61'
WHERE
    ProcedureID = '-747422922' AND
    InitialCharge = '20.72' AND
    (DateOfService >= '2014/09/01' and DateOfService < '2014/10/01')
```

And are you sure the table columns are strings??

Comment: I tried Exists because of the error I was getting, I googled it and someone suggested it. I get the same error with your query as well.

Comment: So when I read the error its saying you cant update when the subquery returns multiple records? Ive never seen this error.

Comment: How could you be getting the same "Subquery returned more than 1 value..." error for this one when there is no subquery.  The best solution may be a good nap ;)

Comment: The InitialCharge field is a decimal but when I remove the single quotes it still errors out

Comment: When you copy & paste the above code, what is the exact error message you receive?

Comment: I found the issue....  There is a trigger on this table :(  That was throwing the error not the query.. This drove me nuts for over an hour... Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Ahh, **that** subquery ;)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't pinned your query down to the specific rows.

Try

```
UPDATE T1
SET InitialCharge = '21.61'
FROM tTransactionHistory T1
WHERE ProcedureID = '-747422922'
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT InitialCharge  
    FROM tTransactionHistory T2
    WHERE T2.ProcedureID = T1.ProcedureID  -- This links the EXISTS to the update
    AND DateOfService BETWEEN '09/01/2014' AND '10/01/2014'
    AND InitialCharge = '20.72')
```

If that's not exactly what you were looking for, I hope you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a trigger on the table, it wasnt the query :(